# Why update and select both is not working with same table

Tags: php, codeigniter

In this query i want to update those records which is latest posted.But my this query is not working please help me what the reason ???

Error :--You can't specify target table 'beevers_products' for update in FROM clause

```
update beevers_products set product_name='my_product_name' where posted_date in (SELECT posted_date FROM `beevers_products` order by posted_date asc limit 1)
```

Comment: In MySQL, you can't modify the same table which you use in the SELECT part. Check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do? This query seems to be inlogical bit

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
UPDATE beevers_products 
SET product_name = 'my_product_name' 
WHERE posted_date = (SELECT posted_date 
                     FROM beevers_products
                     ORDER BY posted_date DESC limit 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Recommend you to use CI Active Record class for querying.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
update beevers_products as t1, 
(select posted_date from beevers_products order by posted_date asc limit 1) as t2
set t1.product_name = 'my_product_name'
where t1.posted_date in (t2.posted_date);
```

You will have to give alias to the record you want and use it in where clause.

Comment: I wana update product_name which is recently added by a single query this query (SELECT posted_date FROM `beevers_products` order by posted_date asc limit 1) is given me latest added date and now i wana update this product....Both query is working seperately fine but combine its not working ???

Comment: That is what i am saying. It will work fine when they are used seperately but when they are used together it will not work. It is just not allowed.

Comment: i have updated my answer. Try it. I have tested and its working.

Comment: Thanks @Bhavik but its not my need ..my need is to update and select both from same table ...with a single query ..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24762/discussion-between-salman-ahmad-and-bhavik-shah)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE beevers_products 
SET product_name = 'my_product_name'  
OUTPUT DELETED.product_name
WHERE posted_date in (SELECT posted_date 
                      FROM `beevers_products` 
                      order by posted_date asc 
                      limit 1)
```

Read more on [output](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/01/sql-server-2005-output-clause-example-and-explanation-with-insert-update-delete/)

Check this -->[Can I update/select from a table in one query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43644/can-i-update-select-from-a-table-in-one-query)
May be it helps you

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO beevers_products (id, product_name)
SELECT id, 'my_product_name'
FROM beevers_products
ORDER BY posted_date ASC
LIMIT 1
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE product_name = VALUES(product_name)
```

Once I learned to use `INSERT ... SELECT ... ON DUPLICATE` so many possibilities surfaced. I'm just a bit curious whenever you want `posted_data ASC` or `posted_data DESC`.